# Spurious wakeups explanation sounds like a bug that just isn't worth fixing, is that right?

Tags: multithreading, bug, features

According to the Wikipedia article on [Spurious Wakeups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup)

> "a thread might be awoken from its waiting state even though no thread signaled the condition variable".

While I've know about this 'feature' I never knew what actually caused it until, in the same article

> "Spurious wakeups may sound strange, but on some multiprocessor systems, making condition wakeup completely predictable might substantially slow all condition variable operations."

Sounds like a bug that just isn't worth fixing, is that right?

Comment: related: "Why does pthread_cond_wait have spurious wakeups?", http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594591/why-does-pthread-cond-wait-have-spurious-wakeups

Answer (score 49):

**TL;DR** Assumption ("contract") of spurious wakeups is a sensible architectural decision made to allow for realistically robust implementations of thread sheduler.

"Performance considerations" are irrelevant here, these are just misunderstanding that became widespread because of having stated in a published authoritative reference. <sup>(authoritative references might have errors, y'know - just ask [Galileo Galilei](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_Galilei))</sup> Wikipedia article keeps the reference to the note you quoted just because it perfectly matches their formal guidelines of citing the published reference.

Much more compelling reason for introducing concept of spurious wakeups is provided in [this answer at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1051816/839601) that is based on additional details provided in an (older version) of that very article:

> The Wikipedia [article on spurious wakeups](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Spurious_wakeup&oldid=289803065) has this tidbit:
>
> > The `pthread_cond_wait()` function in Linux is implemented using the `futex` system call. Each blocking system call on Linux returns abruptly with `EINTR` when the process receives a signal. ... `pthread_cond_wait()` can't restart the waiting because it may miss a real wakeup in the little time it was outside the `futex` system call...

Just think of it... like any code, thread scheduler may experience temporary blackout due to something abnormal happening in underlying hardware / software. Of course, care should be taken for this to happen as rare as possible, but since there's no such thing as 100% robust software it is reasonable to assume this *can* happen and take care on the graceful recovery in case if scheduler detects this (eg by observing missing *heartbeats*).

Now, how could scheduler recover, taking into account that during blackout it could miss some signals intended to notify waiting threads? If scheduler does nothing, mentioned "unlucky" threads will just hang, waiting forever - to avoid this, scheduler would simply send a signal to all the waiting threads.

This makes it necessary to establish a "contract" that waiting thread can be notified without a reason. To be precise, there would be a reason - scheduler blackout - but since thread is designed (for a good reason) to be oblivious to scheduler internal implementation details, this reason is likely better to present as "spurious".

---

From thread perspective, this somewhat resembles a **Postel's law** (aka [robustness principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postel%27s_law)),

> be conservative in what you do, be liberal in what you accept from others

Assumption of spurious wakeups forces thread to be *conservative in what it does*: set condition when notifying other threads, and *liberal in what it accepts*: check the condition upon any return from wait and repeat wait if it's not there yet.

Comment: Ugh... Postel's law... the reason why HTML and all sorts of web technologies have so much crap thrown into them (e.g. HTML acceptance of bad tag nesting). That aside, good answer.

Comment: Postel's law is why  many bugs go uncaught for years because hey, even if your function returns the wrong output, the app still seems to work! Best invention ever.

Comment: @Pacerier: the function returning a wrong output isn't following Postel's law (conservative part).

Comment: @Pacerier: OTOH, demanding other components to be strict so bugs can be caught earlier is an interesting position, erring on the side of 'Fail Fast' principle and 'Contract Based' design.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't worth fixing since caller code should use the same treatment (checking the condition) anyway, in order to deal with race condition.

One treatment for two issues, which I summarize by the following:

```
Spurious wakeup:  waiting thread is scheduled before condition has been established.
Forced oversleep: waiting thread is scheduled after condition has been falsified again.
```

Since the later might happen, some went as far as introducing spurious wakeup in the contract:

- to enforce good practices by requiring predicate loops.
- to give some liberty for scheduler implementation (including an emergency recovery option, as pointed by @gnat).

[SO reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8594644/995896)

Comment: I'd like to +1 this, but for the idea that someone intentionally introduced spurious wakeups in order to get callers to add predicate loops to address forced oversleeps. I find that inconceivable.

Comment: 'The intent was to force correct/robust code by requiring predicate loops.' See the provided link.